# Variable in matrix substituting

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to make :

```
a=[b b+1 b+2]
```

Then I want to use it many time in my code with different `b` value.

I tried this way:

```
syms b;
a=[b b+1 b+2];
subs(b,2)
```

The answer become:

```
[ 2, 3, 4]
```

But this is not `uint8` this is `1x3 sym` and this is not useful in my function.
What is the best and the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Why'd you use symbolic math in the first place? You don't need that very often, especially not when your calculations are numeric anyway, see my answer.

Comment: I think u suggest not using symbol because it's making code slow,Isn't that?

Comment: Symbolic is terribly slow, yes. MATLAB is a numeric calculation package, so you'd better let it do what it does best in case you need numerical data. Symbolic math can't help you in this case, not for efficiency, nor for brevity of code. You'd need to use the exact same expression as for numerical analysis, at the cost of a lot of time.

Comment: Why your answer were deleted that was usefull.

Comment: Because you decided to accept an answer that copied my code without acknowledgement and which didn't make any useful points my answer didn't make.

Comment: I think your answer was really useful, And we can learn something extreme about my question, but the accepted one, I think is what I must use exactly in my code. I really appreciate your answer and to thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Updated after erfan comment)*

You can define an anonymous function (that doesn't require a separate file).

Let's call it make_vector:

```
make_vector = @(a)(uint8([a, a+1, a+2]))
```

Now you can call it wherever you want in your script, on whatever number. Let's use it on 2, for instance:

```
>> make_vector(2)

ans =

     2     3     4
```

No symbolic computations involved, so you need no conversions.

Comment: Full functions don't require a separate file either. Hasn't been so for a long time in functions, and with R2016b you can do the same in scripts. Also, the OP wanted `uint8`, you're using `double`.

Comment: The problem for OP was the use of symbolic calculus, obviously it wouldn't be a big difference between uint8 and double. 

Moreover, I was obviously referring to the impossibility to define a function in a script file in all but the latest version of MATLAB.  

Anonymous functions are shorter and more practical, and they can be easily used for repetitive computations.

Comment: You can change it to `@(a) uint8([a, a+1, a+2])` and then everyone is happy.  _There is a big difference between `uint8` and `double`._

Comment: Ok, I know very well that there is a big difference, I just thought that was not relevant for OP's question.